Does bazel native patch function handle empty new files?
I have generated a patch file using git diff to work with bazel.
The patch file contains no-content new files which are in the following form:
diff --git a/some/path/to/file b/some/path/to/file
new file mode 100644
index 00000000000..someindexhere

and bazel build target reports error that
Cannot find file to patch (near line xx), old file name (some/path/to/file) doesn't exist, new file name (some/path/to/file) doesn't exist.

Moreover, when I use patch -p1 < pathfile, it works just fine.
I expected that bazel patch to work with this, if not, how should I do it?

Just to add, bazel native patch works well too with new file with contents inside

You can [edit] your question to clarify it. Doing so is better than using the comments section. Anyhow, did you check the Bazel bugtracker? Maybe that behaviour is already known upstream?
